# Python Tkinter ttk OptionMenu - AttributeError: 'OptionMenu' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter, attributeerror, ttk, optionmenu

Here is the code what im having problem with. I have imported all of the correct things earlier in the program, this is only a small snippet of the whole thing.

```
class addx:
    def __init__(self):
        self.add = Toplevel() 
        self.add.geometry("200x200")

        # Variables
        self.entry_type      = StringVar()
        self.entry_type.set("Not Selected") # Default

        # Labels
        self.type      = Label ( self.add, text="Type: "    ).grid ( column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=5, sticky=E )
        
        # Entrys
        self.entry_type = OptionMenu ( self.add, self.entry_type, "Not Selected","a","b","c" )
        self.entry_type.grid ( column=1, row=0, pady=5, padx=5 )

        # Buttons
        self.submit_button = Button ( self.add, text="Add", command=self.add ).grid ( column=0, row=4, pady=5, padx=5, columnspan=2, sticky=N )

    def add(self):
        add_type = self.entry_type.get()
```

The error that I am getting is:

```
AttributeError: 'OptionMenu' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: don't use the same name for `StringVar()` and `OptionMenu()`

Comment: Also, don't call `grid` in the same line - it assigns e.g. `self.type = None`.